# LWC1702: Invalid LWC imported identifier "createElement"

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment

Validation is failing due to this error . I have created new LWC component, it defaults created test.js file .I have removed and have only my component html,js and meta.xml file .I created PR in GitHub and validation fails .
Can anyone please support here

Comment: Do you have tests folder inside the lwc component?

Comment: `createElement` is used in jest test files

Answer (score 9):

The Jest Unit-Tests should not be deployed to the org.
You need to add a `.forceignore` file to your project.

Use this file as a template: https://github.com/trailheadapps/visualforce-to-lwc/blob/main/.forceignore

Comment: I get the above validation error in the jest test file.  I'm not deploying to the org.  I can see that sfdx Deploy is not deploying the just test js file.  The test passes.  It just fails validation in the __tests__\...test.js file.

Comment: Update: I deleted the import line, but that caused a massive runtime error.  Then I added it back (<ctrl>z).  The runtime error and the validation error are now gone.  Maybe it takes a while for all the configuration to get consumed and active.  Also, my .forceignore file already had the __test__ folder ignored.  The behind-the-scenes magic must have done that.

Comment: Same issue,  I already have __tests__ in my .forceignore file
# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
```

to

```
import { createElement } from '@lwc/engine-dom';
```

and that seems to have taken care of it.